# How should I make this pomodoro timer more useful?

Tags: javascript, html, timer

A few weeks ago I made a simple Pomodoro-technique timer using HTML5 canvas. I think the website looks stylish but the timer has very limited functionality.

I don't have much experience about Pomodoro technique. I have implemented all the features that are necessary, I think. I have a very few returning users but the website is not so popular. What additional features should I add to attract more users?

I'm thinking about adding a callback API and create an independent logging app, which could use the timer through the API to log activities. Do you think it's a good idea?

You can check the timer app here: http://tomatoro.com

Comment: any status update kdani?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is the best place for this type of question, why not try the [Google Timer Group](http://groups.google.com/group/pomodorotechnique-timer)?

Having said that, can I suggest your problem is you "don't have much experience about Pomodoro Technique". Start using the Pomodoro Technique. Start [dog fooding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food) your timer. Understand the Pomodoro Technique. Once you are familiar with how the Pomodoro Technique works, good ideas about how you could improve your application should become obvious to you.

Answer (score 1):

Just downloaded the trial and did a fast overview of Pomodoro system.

First the timer should run in the background.
Some of the things I do I do on the phone.  Kitchen timer does well at this.

Exporting an apple day to a document would help to evaluate the day.

Also to put the interrupted task to do future category and have future tasks sorted by day to be able to defer tasks to another day or un-catagorized. Tasks can then be sorted into items for today.

Thank you for this manner of reply.